# Counting Child Rows As a Condition in a Query

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord, count

I have a table of Groups that have a "capacity" column and has a has_many relationship with Enrollments. I want to be able to find Groups whose count of enrollments is less than it's capacity, so using ActiveRecord + Ruby I can do this:

```
Group.all.select {|g| g.enrollments.count < g.capacity }.first
```

But it seems like there should be a way to do this in SQL, I just don't know how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pure SQL way of doing this would be

```
select groups.* from groups
    inner join enrollments on enrollments.group_id = groups.id
group by groups.id
having count(*) < capacity
```

Or in activerecord

```
Group.joins(:enrollments).group('groups.id').having('count(*) < capacity)
```

A counter cache with an index on the counter column will be faster though, although obviously you have to not create enrollments behind acriverecord's back.

Answer (score 0):

May use :counter_cache option.

1. Add a enrollments_count column to the Groups table

   ```
   column :groups, :enrollments_count, :integer, :default => 0
   ```
2. set Enrollment's  :counter_cache option

   ```
   class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :group, :counter_cache => true
   end
   ```
3. Group.where("capacity > enrollments_count").first